# A way to allow testers to run tests on Selenium Grid

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

This is basically a question asking for advice, not sure if that's frowned upon so feel free to close if inappropriate.

I've got a Selenium project running remotely on Selenium Grid through Maven on TeamCity. A test is run by calling

```
mvn clean verify -DsomeParameter=parameter -DtestSuite=**/SomeTestSuite
```

We're trying to find a way to allow our testers to run the tests by means of choosing suites and pressing one button.

Now, the easiest way would be to give them access to TeamCity where they could change the build step parameter -DtestSuite. However, that is not an ideal solution as it could lead to testers potentially making a mistake or being overwhelmed.

We'd like to have a simpler (from tester's point of view) solution - some way where they could get a list of suites, choose one and click Run.

I know that TeamCity jobs can also take parameters, but I haven't been able to make this work. The Maven build step is run though a Command Line command because TC needs to connect to the remote server/Grid, so a regular Maven step with additional parameters is not a possibility.

Comment: you can define a drop-down list parameter that will be prompted on build and pass it to your command line, so pass it to mvn.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the mistake I've been doing - for command line parameters it's necessary to define them as environmental variables and use them in the build steps. Works fine now!

p.s. thanks @daggett for the hint